# grep -E for linux date time string

Tags: linux, grep

hi i want the date and time of the following content

```
"text text Sat Mar  4 12:13:23 IST 2017 text text blah:blah"
```

i used the following command but unable to finish it because the date is starting with single number 4 instead of 04

```
grep -Eo '\w{3} \w{3} '
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep:

```
echo "text text Sat Mar  4 12:13:23 IST 2017 text text blah:blah" | grep -Eo '[^ ]{3} [^ ]{3} [0-9 ]{2} [0-9:]{7,8} [^ ]+ [0-9]{4}'
```

Output:

```
Sat Mar  4 12:13:23 IST 2017
```

---

Reference: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)